# Appearing lines

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My problem is that I have appearing lines in excel after I write something and click "Enter" or any other button.

[image]

How can I stop it?

Here, there are screenshots of my macros
enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Press alt & F11. Give a screenshot of what you see there.

Comment: What exactly I should show you? Because I have some macros there.

Comment: The macros. :) Seach for `Worksheet_Change` and `Worksheet_SelectionChange` and put whatever you find in the question.

Comment: I don't have any of these functions.

Comment: Try again. Select Current Project, when you search (see the answer with a screenshot).

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to find this but I have not found anything, but thank you :)

Comment: if you do not show your VBA code it would be not possible to show you why it is happening.

Comment: OK, I've done it

Answer (score 0):

In general, you have some "macros" in the worksheet. Do the following:

- **Make a copy of the file. Or better 2 copies.**
- Open the VBA Editor and search for `Worksheet_Change` and `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. When you are searching, use "Current Project:

[image]

- Delete anything.
- Now it should be ok.